# QT for cross platform plugin development?

Tags: qt, plugins, cross-platform, qtplugin

I have a pre-existing application, that calls out into a plugin library. I want the plugin library to be developed in Qt, and to be able to display a Qt UI.

However, when I attempt to create a `QWidget` it complains that the `QApplication` needs to be created first.

Is it not possible to use Qt to develop cross platform plugins?
E.g. a netscape plugin for Chrome or Firefox. I do not, and cannot, control the app's main loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explain in the [Qt documentation](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html#details), any GUI application using Qt needs a [`QApplication`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qapplication.html) to be created into main thread since it is containing all signal engine and event loop.

Comment: The Qt documentation for Qt 3.3 referenced some classes for creating netscape plugins in Qt 3.3 :- http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/netscape-plugin.html
This stuff seems to have gone "missing" in 4.6 :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is Qt/MFC Migration Framework that can help you to build plugins if the main application where the plugin is laoded is Win32 or Mfc. [Qt/MFC Migration Framework](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/add-on-products/catalog/4/Windows/qtwinmigrate)